# don't auto-return by-columns with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Sample data:

```
dt = data.table(a=c(10,20,30,40),b=c(40,30,20,10),c=c(0,0,1,1))
rank_a = dt[,rank(a)]
rank_a
```

> [1] 1 2 3 4

This returns what I want. However, if I add a by statement,

```
rank_a = dt[,rank(a),by=c]
```

...then it returns a whole data frame including the by column "c", not just the answers I want.

How to fix this behavior?

Comment: If you need a vector, just extract with `$` or `[[` i.e. `dt[,rank(a),by=c]$V1`  As we don't provide the column name, it will be by default named as 'V1'

Comment: Fwiw, I made a vague request for some easier way to do this https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2061 but I would do it the way akrun suggested.

Comment: Copy that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the other columns because they are necessary to understand the output. If, for instance you have a dataset:

```
a    b
1    1
1    2
2    3
2    4
```

.. and you run:

```
dt[, sum(b), a]
```

The output will look like:

```
V1    a
3     1
7     2
```

This makes sense because without the "a" column, the output wouldn't make any sense, as you wouldn't know which V1 values correspond to which "a" groupings. If you really want to get rid of the columns after an operation like this, you can just take the result with something like
`dt[, sum(b), a][, V1]`

or as a data.table with

```
dt[, sum(b), a][, .(V1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution to remove one or multiple "by" columns could be to use `mget` + chaining:

```
dt = data.table(a=c(10,20,30,40),b=c(40,30,20,10),c=c(0,0,1,1),d=c(0,0,0,1))
dt
#     a  b c d
# 1: 10 40 0 0
# 2: 20 30 0 0
# 3: 30 20 1 0
# 4: 40 10 1 1

by.cols = c("c", "d")

# group by one or multiple columns without returning the "group by" columns
# (includes code of @Frank now, see comment)
dt[, .(rank=rank(a)),by = by.cols] [, -(1:length(by.cols))]
#    rank
# 1:    1
# 2:    2
# 3:    1
# 4:    1
#
# OLD code (before including the code snippets from @Frank)
# dt[, .(rank = rank(a)),by=mget(by.cols)] [, -(1:length(by.cols))]
```

Not pretty, but working.

PS: Is there a better way to exclude columns from a `data.table` whose names are stored in a character vector?

Comment: For your PS, `data.tables` are `data.frames` so you can just do `dt[, -char_vec]`

Comment: @Ryan `mtcars[, -"mpg"]` is not a thing, fyi; it works with a data.table `data.table(mtcars)[, -"mpg"]` because that package added that syntax. A little simpler without mget and with seq_along, I think `dt[, .(rank = rank(a)),by=by.cols][, -seq_along(by.cols), with=FALSE]` re a better way, yes `dt[, .(rank = rank(a)),by=by.cols][, !..by.cols]` should work at some point (but doesn't yet on my computer ... data.table 1.10.4-3).

Comment: @Frank perfectly minimized code, your proposal :-) BTW: I was surprised that `[, -(1:length(by.cols))]` does work without `, with = FALSE` while `[, -seq_along(by.cols), with = FALSE]` requires it (could be `data.table`-internal issue).